# DevExpress Gridlookup not updating on event handler

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I am utilizing a DevExpress GridLookup element in a formview of an ASPX page. Now, I have successfully gotten the program to fire off the event handler and even have the BLL properly returning a dataset, with a return of 1 table. This particular chain of events was working only a month ago when I went to working on other things. However, now, in final testing, the gridlookup started failing. Provided below is the markup relevant:

```
<tr>
                        <td class="TableCaptionCell">
                            <strong>
                                <dx:ASPxLabel ID="LocationLabel" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Location" Theme="Office2010Silver">
                                </dx:ASPxLabel>
                            </strong>
                        </td>
                        <td class="TableValueCell" colspan="1">
                            <dx:ASPxGridLookup ID="ShopLocationLookup" ClientInstanceName="ShopLocationLookup" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsShopLocation" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Theme="Office2010Silver" KeyFieldName="value" ValidationSettings-CausesValidation="True" ValidationSettings-ErrorDisplayMode="Text" ValidationSettings-ErrorText="This is required" Value='<%# Bind("ShopLocationId") %>' OnValueChanged="ShopLocationLookup_ValueChanged">

                                <Columns>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="value" VisibleIndex="0"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="text" VisibleIndex="1"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                </Columns>

                                <%--<ClientSideEvents ValueChanged="function(s, e) {
                                        StorageAgreementLookup.GetGridView().PerformCallback();
                                    }"></ClientSideEvents>--%>

                            </dx:ASPxGridLookup>
                        </td>
                        <td class="TableCaptionCell">
                            <dx:ASPxLabel ID="StorageAgreementLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Id" Text="Storage Agreement" Theme="Office2010Silver">
                            </dx:ASPxLabel>
                        </td>
                        <td class="TableValueCell">
                            <dx:ASPxGridLookup ID="StorageAgreementLookup" ClientInstanceName="StorageAgreementLookup" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsStorageAgreementGlobal" Theme="Office2010Silver" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableTheming="True" KeyFieldName="Id" ValidationSettings-SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationSettings-ErrorDisplayMode="ImageWithTooltip" ValidationSettings-ValidationGroup="Profile" ValidationSettings-CausesValidation="True" ValidationSettings-ErrorText="An agreement choice is required. If this dropdown is empty, please select a shop location first." Value='<%# Bind("StorageAgreementId") %>'>

                                <Columns>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Agreement" VisibleIndex="3">
                                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="RatePeriodId" VisibleIndex="5"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="RatePeriod" VisibleIndex="6"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="StorageRate" VisibleIndex="7"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="SwitchInRate" VisibleIndex="8"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="SwitchOutRate" VisibleIndex="9"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CherryPickingRate" VisibleIndex="10"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataDateColumn FieldName="EffectiveDate" VisibleIndex="11"></dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataDateColumn FieldName="ExpirationDate" VisibleIndex="12"></dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
                                </Columns>
                                <ClientSideEvents
                                    Validation="function(s, e) {
                                        if(s.GetValue() == `0`) {
                                            e.isValid = false;
                                            e.errorText = `You must select a Storage Agreement. If the Storage Agreement has no selection, remember to update the Shop Location first.`;
                                        }
                                    }">
                                </ClientSideEvents>

                            </dx:ASPxGridLookup>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
...


<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsStorageAgreementGlobal" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetDataByShopLocationId" TypeName="Storage.Agreements.Agreement">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="shopLocationId" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

The Event Handler for the ShopLocationLookup element:

```
Protected Sub ShopLocationLookup_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim ShopLookup As ASPxGridLookup = DirectCast(sender, ASPxGridLookup)
        Dim selectedShopLocationId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(ShopLookup.GridView.GetRowValues(ShopLookup.GridView.FocusedRowIndex, "value"))

        Dim agreementLookup As ASPxGridLookup = DirectCast(Me.StorageBillFormview.FindControl("StorageAgreementLookup"), ASPxGridLookup)
        Dim agreementGridView As ASPxGridView = agreementLookup.GridView

        odsStorageAgreementGlobal.SelectParameters("shopLocationId").DefaultValue = selectedShopLocationId
'Below is the line the error occurs on. All I get is a System.InvalidOperationException error. Visual Studio can't seem to figure out where aside from System.Web.dll
        agreementGridView.DataBind()



    End Sub
```

The BLL calls and receives a proper ResultSet (tested in SSMS). So the BLL works on its own, but some other step in the Databind method is breaking and I'm not sure what to do with it

I tried multiple ways so far to get as far as I have. Because of how formviews are handled in C#, none of the controls are directly accessible through the events, and setting the ODS outside of the formview itself was the only way in which I could properly access the thing to set the parameters in the first place. I have confirmed that the proper parameter was passed through. By default the ods is set to 0, and the event handler sets the parameter to the location id chosen by the end user in the shoplocationlookup. That is correct. The error occurs after the bll fires, but before the Databind() method finishes.
Below is the exception in the output:

Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Web.dll

The company's license for Devexpress is not current and I cannot find anything for this happening when the error is NOT "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control". For that, it is simple, you databind from the embedded gridview and not the lookup.

Comment: as an alternative, this task can be easily manipulated by using javascript. Use FetchAPI to get data from backend in real time. by using Javascript, you will total and direct control of how to render each elements.